# jQuery Ajax: insert to <div> sometimes fails?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I uses jQuery Ajax a lot to update a div in HTML pages. The ajax is included in $(document).read(...) such as the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.button').click(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').load(url);
    return false;
  });
});
```

However, after clicking the button, Ajax sometimes fails and it displays the result in the whole page, instead in the 'content' div. This happened frequently when the page is loading or refreshed. But I suppose that $(document).ready(...) would prevent this from happening. What went wrong?

Comment: Can you try by setting the "async: false" in ajax request?

Comment: @Samuel Liew: no there is only one script.

Comment: @Nadeem: according to http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/, "async: false" is deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ajax sometimes fails and it displays the result in the whole page

This suggest that the hyperlink was not selected with the selector `a.button`. Make sure that the hyperlinks you want loaded via AJAX has the class name `button`, like so:

```
<a class="button" href="...">
```

If you want ALL hyperlinks to load via AJAX, remove the button selector.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').click(function() {
    ... ...
  });
});
```

If some hyperlinks are dynamically created after page load by another script, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('click', 'a', function() {
    ... ...
  });
});
```

Comment: 1) All buttons have the class="button, 2) In my page, there are other links that don't require ajax, 3) As I said, it happened *sometimes*, so the selector did work *sometimes*.

Comment: Hmmm..., that seems to work. I'll try more to see how it performs. Thanks a million, Samuel.

Comment: Well, after some experiments, jQuery ajax still **sometimes* displays the result in the whole page instead in the designated div, and this happened mostly at the first visit of the page. I am on Google App Engine, and the contend and the code that triggers the Ajax is inserted by the template engine using {% include "someHTML.html" %}. Is that the problem?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('a.button').click(function () {
     var url = $(this).attr('href');        

    $.get(url, function(data) {
       $('#content').html(data);    
        });
     });
});
```

Comment: Now the result is displayed in the whole page all the time, instead of in the div.

Comment: Yes, it's correct. The solution provided by Samual works well.

Comment: Still didn't work. The returned data show in a whole page, not in the designated div.