# jQuery: one click triggers multiple events

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a login form in which there are two links of `Add member` and `Reset password`. I also used jQuery Ajax to update the corresponding div's. I am working on Google App Engine and Python. The codes are as follows:

base.html:

```
...
<div id="loginDiv">{% include "login.html" %}</div>
...
```

login.html:

```
<a href="/login?arg1=resetPassword" class="resetPassword">Reset Password</a>
<a href="/addMember" class="addMember">Add member</a>

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Add member
  $('body').on('click', 'a.addMember', function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').load(url);
      return false;
  });
  // Reset password
  $('body').on('click', 'a.resetPassword', function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#loginDiv').load(url);
      return false;
  });
});
```

The problem is: when I click one of the buttons, multiple events will be triggered. Does the problem come from my wrong usage of jQuery's `$('body')`?

Comment: Why not just use `$("a.addMember").click(...)` and `$("a.resetPassword").click(...)`?

Comment: Those were exactly what I used before. However, sometimes the Ajax wouldn't update the designated div; instead it update to a whole page (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452952/jquery-ajax-insert-to-div-sometimes-fails). So I took Samuel's suggestion. I still don't know why it was not working.

Comment: Maybe you better load only part of the returned contents e.g. `$('#content').load(url + " body");` so that you won't put `<html>` and stuff like that into your placeholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are not running that javascript code more than once, if the code is being loaded through ajax that will happen.

A quick fix would be to do something like:

```
$('body').off('click','a.resetPassword');
$('body').on('click', 'a.resetPassword', function() { ...
```

Comment: I have re-edit my question by adding descriptions about the `base.html` and `login.html` files. As far as I can see, I don't think the javascript will be loaded multiple times (the whole `loginDiv` is replaced). Am I wrong?

Comment: No problem, but notice that if it worked it means you are running the .on more than once, you may want to consider moving that javascript up to content that is not loaded through ajax. The solution in the answer is not optimal, its just a quick fix :)

Comment: Hi cernunnos, many thanks for your explanation. Would you be so kind to further elaborate why the `.on()` javascript is executed more than once? Initially, the `loginDiv` div is loaded with the `login.html` file, which contains html and javascript codes. And then, `loginDiv` is updated also with the same file. Wouldn't the update completely replace the old data such that there won't be multiple copies of the javascript? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It replaces the data in the element, but the event handler is attached to the "body" element (and delegated to any a.resetPassword elements within the body), and the body element has not been replaced. So you are attaching a new event handler to the same element, instead of replacing the existing one. That is why .off() works as a quick fix, it clears any event handler created by .on() with the same selector from the element before attaching a new one, ensuring you only have 1. This can result in unwanted side effects though (if you actually wanted to have 2 or more different handlers).

Answer (score 1):

Use following code

```
$("a.resetPassword").click(function(){
                                        // Write your logic here
                                     });

$("a.addMember").click(function(){
                                        // Write your logic here
                                     });
```

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to DRY your code like this:

HTML:

```
<a href="/login?arg1=resetPassword" class="loadLink" data-target="#loginDiv">Reset Password</a>
<a href="/addMember" class="loadLink" data-target="#content">Add member</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {

  $('body').on('click', 'a.loadLink', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $( $this.data('target') ).load($this.attr('href'));
    return false;

  });

});
```

You use a single class, then rely on the `data-target` attribute to tell js where to load href content.